# почему process.env не работает в app.js но работает в webpack.config.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, .env, webpack5

почему process.env не работает в файле app.js, но работает в webpack.config.js? У меня есть собственный вебпак, который я создала сама. Он не был создан с CRA.

Я хочу вывести версию на консоль, чтобы увидеть версию вебпака. Но я не могу этого сделать, хотя я сделала необходимые настройки. если я вывожу данные в webpack, то все работает корректно, если я вывожу данные в простой js файл, то вижу undefinded. в общем, я хочу сделать версию видимой на сервере после сборки, и я хочу сделать это таким образом. Можно просто вывести console.log, но это похоже на неправильное решение console.log('ver 1.74. 2')

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.scss";

const onClickEvent = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("You Clicked Me!");
};

const App = () => {
  console.log(process.env.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION);
  return (
    <div className={styles.content}>
      <div className={styles.label}>OWN WEBPACK</div>
      <button className={styles.btn} onClick={onClickEvent}>
        Click Me 
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
console.log(process.env.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION);

module.exports = {
  entry: { myAppName: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js") },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: production ? "[name].[contenthash].js" : "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          production ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: !production,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: !production,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".scss"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new Dotenv(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Webpack & React",
      template: "./src/index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: production ? "[name].[contenthash].css" : "[name].css",
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      "process.env.MY_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_ENV),
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    hot: true,
  },
  mode: production ? "production" : "development",
};
```

---

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node server/index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development test=$TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:watch": "NODE_ENV=development node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
```

---

```
//server/index.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.log('in development.');
} else {
    console.log('in production.');
}

/* App Config */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));


/* Server Initialization */
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server initialized on: http://localhost:${port} // ${new Date()}`));
```

---

Comment: Смею предположить что app.js это статический файл, в то время как webpack.config.js у вас выполняется через node. В статическом файле у вас нет ни какого процесса.

Comment: версию так правильно выводить? или можно как нибудь другим способом вывести? или её лучше вообще не воводить? так как мне кажется так тоже не правильно так как файл env должен быть в исключение и на сервере при билде наверное ничего не будет известно про версию...